# Error 500 InternalServerError when use httprequest call API (python flask) with long time response

Tags: python, c#, iis, httpresponse, wfastcgi

I build a service to call API from Python flask. This is my Service

```
public string CheckStatus(string json)
    {
        Utils log = new Utils();
        string ResponseString = "";
        HttpWebResponse response = null;
        try
        {
            string schedulingAPIUrl = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SchedulingAPI_URL"];
            var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(string.Format(schedulingAPIUrl + "{0}", "CheckStatus"));
            request.Accept = "application/json";
            request.Method = "POST";
            request.Timeout = Timeout.Infinite;
            request.KeepAlive = true;
            var myContent = json;
            
            var data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(myContent);

            request.ContentType = "application/json";
            request.ContentLength = data.Length;

            using (var stream = request.GetRequestStream())
            {
                stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
            }

            response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
            ResponseString = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();
        }
        catch (WebException ex)
        {
            if (ex.Status == WebExceptionStatus.ProtocolError)
            {
                response = (HttpWebResponse)ex.Response;
                ResponseString = "Some error occurred: " + response.StatusCode.ToString();
            }
            else
            {
                ResponseString = "Some error occurred: " + ex.Status.ToString();
            }
        }
        return ResponseString;
    }
```

My Service will transfer a parameter is a list of many dictionaries to my API. If the Parameter has an amount of ~ 10000 dictionaries, everything is ok. But If it has to amount to 1 million dictionaries or more, after my API run 8-10minutes, I get an error: "500 InternalServerError".

I use wfastcgi, IIS to deploy my API.

I don't know the reason for the 500 error being from my Service or my API.

Comment: reconsider before sending millions of data. you should implement streaming api for such large data trasnsfer.

Comment: I will do that, but when I send data completed and run in 5-10p I just got an error. I will update my post clearly now.

Comment: 500 error means there's some unhandled exception(in your c# code) you may need add more logs in server. did you ever check the server log?

Comment: Yes, I did. The error exist from line code `ResponseString = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();` so I think I can't add more logs in server

Comment: if you did check the log, then show the log. there should be errors with call stack trace.

Comment: did you mean server log? Is it my service log or my server deploy API log? If it is my service log, I know the line exist error ` ResponseString = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();`. If it is my server deploying my API, it does not exist any errors. It's so weird

Comment: I know the line exist error --- show the errors.

Comment: @LeiYang, the error in server log just is: "Some error occurred: InternalServerError"

Comment: it is client error, you need paste server error here.

Comment: I'm sorry so much if my answer and question made you uncomfortable, I'm confused between client error and server error. My server is window 10, so I need to check the window 10 services log?

Comment: i'm also confused. if your work flow is c# as client, post to flask, then check flask logs.

Comment: my flask logs are nothing, I don't give any error log from flask logs, it's so weird. I'm sure I write errors to log if have errors

Comment: then check the proxy logs, such as uwsgi if you're using such.

Comment: I get information in proxy logs: "wfastcgi.py will restart when files in D:\www\SchedulingAPI\app\ are changed" and not show any error

Comment: It's seem error from IIS, I get an error when I test API in postman : `The FastCGI process exceeded configured activity timeout`

Comment: ok. so you really need refactor to stream way, instead of possibly increasing timeout/message size.

Comment: @ToanNguyenPhuoc Please do not use WebRequest, WebClient to make API calls since they are marked as obsolete: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/networking/6.0/webrequest-deprecated . Please use the `System.Net.Http.HttpClient` class instead.

Comment: You can use failed request tracking to view detailed error information.